# Firebase admin.auth.createUser error ( nodejs+Typescript+firebase-admin)

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get an error `error TS2339: Property 'createUser' does not exist on type 'FirebaseServiceInterface'.` when I try to transpile Typescript on nodejs. I'm using `firebase-admin 4.0.4` and typescript `2.0.6`. What could be the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to at least [version 4.0.5 of the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#4.0.5). That version included a bunch of fixes for the TypeScript typings, including this particular issue. Simply upgrading to at least that version should make your issue just go away.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out today

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem with the database() object being identified as a FirebaseServiceInterface and I'm 99% sure it is a problem with the typings for this version of firebase-admin. Hopefully it will be resolved soon in a future update.

I was able to ignore the error and everything worked fine. I was also able to eliminate the error by typing my database object as `<any>`, so instead of this:

```
var fbDatabase = admin.database();
```

I did this:

```
var fbDatabase: any = admin.database();
```

That eliminated the error but also disabled Intellisense for the database object (can't have it both ways).

Comment: Hey, Jacob from the Firebase team here. There are a handful of known issues with the TypeScript typings for the Admin Node.js SDK. I actually spent a bunch of time today fixing them up and the next release of the SDK should work much better. In the meantime, use the `any` trick to get TypeScript to accept your typings. Sorry for the inconvenience. Expect a new release in the coming week or two.

Comment: If you also have the normal Firebase SDK in your project, I found that you can cast it to the Firebase Database type, which gives you a little better type safety: ```let database: firebase.database.Database = admin.database() as any;```

Comment: We released [version 4.0.5 of the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#4.0.5) earlier today which has a bunch of fixes for the TypeScript typings, including this particular issue. Please upgrade to this latest version and hopefully your issue just goes away.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node.js and working with firebase cloud functions, you may create user like this

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email: "user@example.com",
  emailVerified: false,
  phoneNumber: "+11234567890",
  password: "secretPassword",
  displayName: "John Doe",
  photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
  disabled: false
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user